# How to write Dynamic routes for express server ( nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have written crud routes

`

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const db = require('./user_crud_queries')
const port = 3000
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
)
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({
        info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API'
    })
})
app.get('/users', db.getUsers)
app.get('/users/:id', db.getUserById)
app.post('/users', db.createUser)
app.put('/users/:id', db.updateUser)
app.delete('/users/:id', db.deleteUser)
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

`

if i have 100 tables do i have to include 100 files?  Can it be imported dynamically based on call?

I did create generic crud but i dont want to give that to client because they expect it to be detailed. So 100 tables means 100 separate file for each table. if sever include all 100 tables , will the memory is enough?

Answer (score 1):

So what you can instead do is create a file called users.routes.js/ts and include all of it like this :

```
import { Router } from "express";

router
.route("/users")
.get(db.getUsers)
.post(db.createUser)

router
.route("/users/:id")
.get('/users/:id', db.getUserById)
.delete('/users/:id', db.deleteUser)




export default router;
```

and then in the app.js/ts you can user it like this :

```
import userRouter from "./routes/user.routes";

app.use("/api", userRouter);
```

So now you can use the following endpoint :

/api/users or /api.users/:id

But yes, if there are 100 tables you will have to use 100 different files for all the CRUD operation that is there, only this will make the code readability easy. Also, you can use different microservice for the same job and reduce the tables for a single server to handle.

Comment: I will use tablename=user  as make it a single file. queries will dynamic search will be dynamic. crud do not need complex search. just paging and sorting and simple field search

Comment: app.use("/qapi/", query_routes );
app.use("/api/:tablename/",  crud_routes);

Comment: crud_routes.js will have this .....  const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
    //update user
    router.post("/create", verifyToken, createRow);
    //update user
    router.put("/:id", verifyToken, updateRow);
    //delete user
    router.delete("/:id", verifyToken, deleteRows);
     //get a user
    router.get("/:id",verifyToken, getRow);
    //get a users
    router.get("/:id",verifyToken, getRows);
    // get user comments
    router.get("/:id/:childtablename",verifyToken, getRowChilds);

Comment: You can do this. But this will work only for operations if none of the entities in your tables have refrence to each other

Comment: If you have to use some x table which has some refrencing from some y table, this concept will not work

Comment: Generic CRUD - is done. its for each table. No relation to each other. I can apply to any future tables. Custom queries direct sql. Better than prisma. For that alos i did generic crud. Then realised i only have 3 files for my own sql crud but prisma has 1000files.